# Cannot ignore lines in code coverage using Istanbul

Tags: angular, typescript, intellij-idea, karma-jasmine, istanbul

I have seen a lot of code samples which use

/* istanbul ignore next */
/* istanbul ignore start */
/* istanbul ignore end */

There are a few places in the codebase which can't ever be reached by unit tests, and it would be nice to use these Istanbul directives to ignore them. Unfortunately, despite installing, reinstalling, editing config files, etc., I cannot get this working.

I am using the following:

- IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.4 (Ultimate Edition)
- JetBrains Karma Plugin (212.4746.57)
- Angular and AngularJS Plugin (212.5712.43)
- Javascript and Typescript Plugin (212.5712.43)
- Node Plugin (212.5712.43)
- node 14.15.5
- npm 6.14.11
- @angular-* 14.0.1
- jasmine 4.2.0
- jasmine-core 4.2.0
- jasmine-reporters 2.5.0
- karma 6.4.0
- karma-chrome-launcher 3.1.1
- karma-cli 2.0.0
- karma-coverage 2.2.0
- karma-jasmine 5.0.1
- source-map-support 0.5.21
- ts-helpers 1.12
- ts-node 10.8.1
- tslib 2.4.0
- typescript 4.7.3

From my research, it seems that Istanbul is included as part of karma-coverage, although I have seen various istanbul related packages.

My karma.conf.js file is:

```
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/2.0/config/configuration-file.html
// This is for running locally in intellij - the intellij plugin doesn't support the parallel options we use via jenkins

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    files: [
      'src/**/*.js'
    ],
    // coverage reporter generates the coverage
    reporters: ['progress', 'coverage'],
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-firefox-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage'),
      require('karma-junit-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false, // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
      jasmine: {
        verboseDeprecations: true
      }
    },
    // you can define custom flags
    customLaunchers: {
    },
    mime: {
      'text/x-typescript': ['ts','tsx']
    },
    preprocessors: {
      'src/**/*.js': ['coverage']
    },
    coverageReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, 'coverage'),
      // subdir: '.',
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true,
      reporters: [
        // reporters not supporting the `file` property
        //{ type: 'html', subdir: 'report-html' },
        { type: 'lcov' /*, subdir: 'report-lcov' */ },
        // reporters supporting the `file` property, use `subdir` to directly
        // output them in the `dir` directory
        //{ type: 'cobertura', subdir: '.', file: 'cobertura.txt' },
        //{ type: 'text-summary', subdir: '.', file: 'text-summary.txt' },
        //{ type: 'lcovonly', subdir: '.', file: 'report-lcovonly.txt' },
        //{ type: 'text', subdir: '.', file: 'text.txt' },
      ]
    },
    junitReporter: {
      outputDir: 'test-results/unit/',
      outputFile: 'test-results.xml'
    },
    reporters: config.angularCli && config.angularCli.codeCoverage
      ? ['progress', 'coverage', 'junit']
      : ['progress', 'kjhtml', 'junit'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG, // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    hostName: 'localhost',
    autoWatch: true,
    usePolling: true,
    singleRun: true,
    // browsers: ['Chrome'],
    browsers: ['ChromeHeadless'],
    // browsers: ['Firefox'],
    captureTimeout: 180000,
    browserNoActivityTimeout : 210000,
    reportSlowerThan : 500,
    retryLimit: 0,                      // Fixes the issue where karma was starting up 3 browser tabs
    browserDisconnectTimeout : 210000, // default 2000
    browserDisconnectTolerance : 1, // default 0
    random: false
  });
};
```

Looking at the Karma Server window, I see no mention of the word "istanbul". I have no indication that istanbul is being used at all. Judging by the sheer use of the // istanbul directives, this is not an unusual thing to do. I would appreciate suggestions on how to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Must be https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-coverage/issues/247, istanbul ignore annotations are not respected by karma coverage reporter

Comment: Thanks, lena, but I saw that one already. The only thing is, if this was an outstanding bug, nobody would be using the istanbul ignore directives. But all of the node modules I have downloaded are thick with them, so it must be possible, and shouldn't be too hard!

Comment: istanbul directives work in Jest, for example, I've just verified this. They even do work in karma when using reporters other than karma coverage

Comment: I used the same machine to create a brand new Angular application with the same karma modules as the misbehaving project, added a new line, prepended with istanbul ignore next, to the sample app. Code coverage ignores that line as described in the documentation. I took a copy of the working karma.config.js file and overwrote the misbehaving application's karma.config.js. Sadly this still didn't work. I am currently in the process of removing all the modules from the node project and re-adding them.

Comment: Well, that didn't work. I am now resorting to putting console.warn() statements in the node_modules being used. It looks as if my misbehaving installation is not even loading the VisitState class in the istanbul-lib-instrument module. In my "good" installation, I can see methods being called in this class.